# Is there something like JavaScript's "split()" in the shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script, string

It's very easy to use `split()` in JavaScript to break a string into an array.

What about shell script?

Say I want to do this:

`$ script.sh var1_var2_var3`

When the user give such string `var1_var2_var3` to the script.sh, inside the script it will convert the string into an array like

```
array=( var1 var2 var3 )
for name in ${array[@]}; do
    # some code
done
```

Comment: what `shell` are you using, with `bash` you can do `IFS='_' read -a array <<< "${string}"`

Comment: `perl` can do that too. It's not "pure" shell, but it's quite common.

Comment: @Sobrique I am also unaware of the technical definition of "pure" shell, but there is node.js.

Comment: I tend to work on 'is it probably installed on my linux box by default' and don't fret the minutiae :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bourne/POSIX-like shells have a split+glob operator and it's invoked every time you leave a parameter expansion (`$var`, `$-`...), command substitution (`$(...)`), or arithmetic expansion (`$((...))`) unquoted in list context.

Actually, you invoked it by mistake when you did `for name in ${array[@]}` instead of `for name in "${array[@]}"`. (Actually, you should beware that [invoking that operator like that by mistake is source of many bugs and security vulnerabilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)).

That operator is configured with the `$IFS` special parameter (to tell what characters to split on (though beware that space, tab and newline receive a special treatment there)) and the `-f` option to disable (`set -f`) or enable (`set +f`) the `glob` part.

Also note that while the `S` in `$IFS` was originally (in the Bourne shell where `$IFS` comes from) for <kbd>S</kbd>eparator, in POSIX shells, the characters in `$IFS` should rather be seen as *delimiters* or *terminators* (see below for an example).

So to split on `_`:

```
string='var1_var2_var3'
IFS=_ # delimit on _
set -f # disable the glob part
array=($string) # invoke the split+glob operator

for i in "${array[@]}"; do # loop over the array elements.
```

To see the distinction between *separator* and *delimiter*, try on:

```
string='var1_var2_'
```

That will split it into `var1` and `var2` only (no extra empty element).

So, to make it similar to JavaScript's `split()`, you'd need an extra step:

```
string='var1_var2_var3'
IFS=_ # delimit on _
set -f # disable the glob part
temp=${string}_ # add an extra delimiter
array=($temp) # invoke the split+glob operator
```

(note that it would split an empty `$string` into **1** (not *0*) element, like JavaScript's `split()`).

To see the special treatments tab, space and newline receive, compare:

```
IFS=' '; string=' var1  var2  '
```

(where you get `var1` and `var2`) with

```
IFS='_'; string='_var1__var2__'
```

where you get: `''`, `var1`, `''`, `var2`, `''`.

Note that the `zsh` shell doesn't invoke that split+glob operator implicitly like that unless in `sh` or `ksh` emulation. There, you have to invoke it explicitely. `$=string` for the split part, `$~string` for the glob part (`$=~string` for both), and it also has a split operator where you can specify the separator:

```
array=(${(s:_:)string})
```

or to preserve the empty  elements:

```
array=("${(@s:_:)string}")
```

Note that there `s` is for *splitting*, not *delimiting* (also with `$IFS`, a known POSIX non-conformance of `zsh`). It's different from JavaScript's `split()` in that an empty string is split into 0 (not 1) element.

A notable difference with `$IFS`-splitting is that `${(s:abc:)string}` splits on the `abc` string, while with `IFS=abc`, that would split on `a`, `b` or `c`.

With `zsh` and `ksh93`, the special treatment that space, tab or newline receive can be removed by doubling them in `$IFS`.

<sub>As a historic note, the Bourne shell (the ancestor or modern POSIX shells) always stripped the empty elements. It also had a number of bugs related to splitting and expansion of $@ with non-default values of `$IFS`. For instance `IFS=_; set -f; set -- $@` would not be equivalent to `IFS=_; set -f; set -- $1 $2 $3...`.</sub>

#### Splitting on regexps

Now for something closer to JavaScript's `split()` that can split on regular expressions, you'd need to rely on external utilities.

In the POSIX tool-chest,`awk` has a `split` operator that can split on *extended regular expressions* (those are more or less a subset of the Perl-like regular expressions supported by JavaScript).

```
split() {
  awk -v q="'" '
    function quote(s) {
      gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
      return q s q
    }
    BEGIN {
      n = split(ARGV[1], a, ARGV[2])
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf " %s", quote(a[i])
      exit
    }' "$@"
}
string=a__b_+c
eval "array=($(split "$string" '[_+]+'))"
```

The `zsh` shell has builtin support for Perl-compatible regular expressions (in its `zsh/pcre` module), but using it to split a string, though possible is relatively cumbersome.

Comment: Is there any reason for special treatments with tab, space and newline?

Comment: @cuonglm, generally you want to split on words when the delimiters are blanks, in the case of non-blank delimiters (like to split `$PATH` on `:`) on the contrary, you generally want to preserve empty elements. Note that in the Bourne shell, all characters were receiving the special treatment, `ksh` changed that to have only the blank ones (only space, tab and newline though) treated specially.

Comment: Well, the recent added Bourne shell note surprised me. And for completing, should you add the note for `zsh` treatment with string contains 2 or more characters in `${(s:string:)var}`? If added, I can delete my answer :)

Comment: What do you mean by "Also note that the S in $IFS is for Delimiter, not Separator."? I understand the mechanics and that it ignores trailing separators but the `S` stands for _Separator_, not _delimiter_. At least, that's what my bash's manual says.

Comment: @terdon, `$IFS` comes from the Bourne shell where it was _separator_, ksh changed the behaviour without changing the  name. I mention that to stress that `split+glob` (except in zsh or pdksh) doesn't simply split anymore.

Comment: (I'm looking for a clear explanation of the difference between "delimiter" and "separator", which seems surprisingly hard to find.) Would it be correct to say that the `IFS` characters in the Bourne shell were separators _because_ in that shell the empty elements were always stripped? And that, conversely, in POSIX shells they are delimiters/terminators because any single instance of them delimits (terminates) a possibly empty element?

Comment: @fra-san, in the Bourne shell, `:a::b:` with `IFS=:` was split into `a` and `b`. In shells that treat  `IFS` as separator, it's split into `""`, `a`, `""`, `b` and `""`. In shells that treat it as delimiter, same without the last `""`. That also applied to  `read`. See [Shell read \*sometimes\* strips trailing delimiter](//stackoverflow.com/q/52762210)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use `IFS` and set it to `_`. Then use `read -a` to store into an array (`-r` turns off backslash expansion). Note that this is specific to bash; ksh and zsh have similar features with slightly different syntax, and plain sh doesn't have array variables at all.

```
$ r="var1_var2_var3"
$ IFS='_' read -r -a array <<< "$r"
$ for name in "${array[@]}"; do echo "+ $name"; done
+ var1
+ var2
+ var3
```

From `man bash`:

> **read**
>
> **-a** aname
>
> The  words  are  assigned to sequential indices of the array variable
>   aname, starting at 0.  aname is unset before any new values are
>   assigned.  Other name arguments are ignored.
>
> **IFS**
>
> The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after
>   expansion and to split lines  into words with the read builtin
>   command.  The default value is ``''.

Note that `read` stops at the first newline. Pass `-d ''` to `read` to avoid that, but in that case, there will be an extra newline at the end due to the `<<<` operator. You can remove it manually:

```
IFS='_' read -r -d '' -a array <<< "$r"
array[$((${#array[@]}-1))]=${array[$((${#array[@]}-1))]%?}
```

Comment: That assumes `$r` doesn't contain newline characters or backslashes. Also note that it will only work in recent versions of the `bash` shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point. Yes, this is the "basic" case of a string. For the rest, everyone should go for your comprehensive answer. Regarding the versions of `bash`, `read -a` was introduced in bash 4, right?

Comment: sorry my bad,  I thought `<<<` was added only recently to `bash` but it seems it's been there since 2.05b (2002). `read -a` is even older than that. `<<<` comes from `zsh` and is supported by `ksh93` (and mksh and yash) as well but `read -a` is bash-specific (it's `-A` in ksh93, yash and zsh).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is there any "easy" way to find when these changes happened? I say "easy" not to dig into the release files, maybe a page showing them all.

Comment: I look at change logs for that. zsh also has a git repository with history as far back as 3.1.5 and its mailing list is used for tracking changes as well.

Comment: @Gilles, note that `bash` now supports `${array[-1]}` like `zsh` (also as lvalue). Older versions also support `${array[@]: -1}` like `ksh93`.  Those also work for sparse arrays.